# call id of a table to a new table and insert values to this new table

Tags: mysql, database-administration, json

I have recently started to write server scripts. Although the question may seem to be very basic but i am not able to get a solution.

I have two tables one is PRODUCTS and the other is DEALS.

```
PRODUCTS TABLE:

Id  product_name  product_desc   category    brand
1   product1      desc1          cat1        brand1                                                     
2   product2      desc2          cat2        brand2

DEALS TABLE

Id     deal_name      productid    
1      todayoffer        2
```

I wish to put the value of id (from PRODUCTS table) into productid and carry this value to DEALS table and then add deal_name along with it as shown above. The recent code that i am using is

```
<?
require_once('config.php'); //connection

$dealname=$_REQUEST['dealname'];
$productid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$productid=$_REQUEST['productid'];

$inserts = mysql_query("insert into deals (dealname,productid) SELECT productid FROM products WHERE productid = '".$id."'");


    $posts[0]['message'] = 'Deal Registered';
    $idd = mysql_insert_id();
    $selectt = mysql_query("select * from deals where id = '".$idd."'");

    $posts[0]['detail'] = $selectt;
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($posts);
?>
```

Comment: Where is dealname supposed to come from?

Comment: it will be entered by the application owner. Basically this script is for a shopping app where there will be 5-6 deals for buyers by owner

Comment: You can use a constant in the SQL like this: `"insert into deals (dealname,productid) SELECT '".$dealname."', productid FROM products..."`, but you have larger problems with the usage of mysql: sql injection, no error checking, no fetching of results, etc.